# Using Java's Timer to wait for a period of time between loop iterations

Tags: java, loops, timer, wait

Learning to use the Java Timer.

If I want to print the contents of an iterator inside a loop and wait for say 5 seconds inbetween each print, I could use `Thread.sleep`. But I'm trying to do this without `Thread.sleep`. This is my attempt so far:

```
        do {
            Timer printTimer = new Timer();
            printTimer.schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {  
                    print(myIterator.next().toString()); // using System.out.println internally
                 }
                }, 5000);
        } while (myIterator.hasNext())
```

However, the above basically results in an infinite loop. It doesn't execute the task once per iteration and wait 5 seconds like I could do with `Thread.sleep`. In other words, it doesn't seem to check the `myIterator.hasNext()` condition.

Is there a way to get it to simulate a call to `Thread.sleep(5000)` after printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it seems to be looping infinitely, is because the `myIterator.next()` call doesn't happen until the `TimerTask` is executed, so `myIterator.hasNext()` is not updating on each loop iteration. Try moving the `myIterator.next()` call outside of the `TimerTask` and inside the loop.

You can also maintain a count of each iteration to schedule each task in 5 second increments, as well as reusing the `Timer` instance.

I would also recommend using a `while` loop instead of a `do-while` loop, unless you're certain that your iterator will always have at least one element, or else you may get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Here is a working example:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
int i = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 5000L * i++);
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```java
a // after 0 seconds
b // after 5 seconds
c // after 10 seconds
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Just curious, is it possible to get it to print the first letter immediately (then the second letter at 5 secs and so on)? The iterator does have at least one element.

Comment: Sure! I've updated the answer to reflect that (just needed to change `i` to increment after doing the calculation instead of before, so the first task is scheduled in 0ms instead of 5000ms).